# Snowflake app built in snowflake using streamlit and python-no local enviornment

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a snowflake app. i have tried making it using streamlit and stage it in my snowflake account which worked fine but it shows some errors when using some streamlit functions like file_uploader and option_menu for navbar and snowflake has its own limitations. Due to which i can't make a proper user app.
i want to develop a complete application in snowflake in which there are few menus on top and user can upload files in application which will render its results on another page.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not all Streamlit features are supported in Streamlit in Snowflake. File Uploader is not supported. See [Unsupported Streamlit Features](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/streamlit/limitations#unsupported-streamlit-features) for more information.

Comment: yes i know.  But is there any way i can achieve my target interface. Like lets say i want to create an interface with different menus to navigate and a form to upload file into snowflake database. something like this.

Comment: Deploy outside of Snowflake, such as on Streamlit Cloud.